# NodeJS - Reading image source returns incorrect file size

Tags: node.js, encoding, fs

This could be a basic question, but wanted to understand why the size of the file being read using `fs.readFileSync` is incorrect if the `source` is referring to an 'image' or non-text file path.

Example:

`fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, fs.readFileSync(source, 'utf8'));`

Comment: You should not read binary files as `utf8`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Why shouldn't OP do that? Please expand your comment

Comment: Text encoding is meant to be used for text (human readable) files. Images (unless they are SVGs) are binary.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen. what is the best way to copy two files seamlessly irrespective of the content of the file.

Comment: Simplest would be, just remove `'utf8'` in your code.

Comment: could use binary too, https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling fs.readFileSync(source, 'utf8').

The important part is utf8, you are telling it to decode the file as if it is utf8 text. If it is a non-text file then it will not work properly and thus produce the incorrect file size.